# how to add link to null path in menu in drupal 7

Tags: routes, navigation, uri

I have added superfish menu in menu bar in that one of the link have sub-link. How to add a sub-link with null path.

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [Special menu items](https://drupal.org/project/special_menu_items) module.

> Features:
>
> - User can create a new menu item and place either "<nolink>" or "<separator>" to the Path field, without quotes.
> - "<nolink>" item will be rendered similar to a normal menu link item but there will be no link just the title.
> - You can change HTML tag used for menu item
> - "<separator>" item will be rendered to an item which is no link and by default title will be "-------".
> - Breadcrumb of "<nolink>" will be rendered same as "<nolink>" menu item.
> - CSS class "nolink" is added to "nolink" menu item.
> - CSS class "separator" is added to "separator" menu item.